# Problem sending datas by Excel-VBA to PostgressSQL: [ODBC driver manager] data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: excel, vba, postgresql, database-connection, driver

I need help with a task.

I have a VBA code at Excel to send some datas for PostgressSQL.

These days I reinstalled my Excel, but now, when I try to send the data the VBA presents the message below and the data is not include in my database:

"[ODBC driver manager] data source name not found and no default driver specified"

The debug highlight that the problem is in Conexao.Open. Below is part of the code with this:

```
Sub Conectar_BD()
Set Conexao = New ADODB.Connection
Conexao.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=yyyy; UID=marcel; PASSWORD=xxx;"

Conexao.Open
End Sub
```

Looking for some answers I found the explanation that I have to install the driver, but I´m not sure about how I could do that.

However, researching more I discovered a tutorial teaching how to connect the driver by admnistrative tool in the panel of control of windows called Datasource ODBC.

Following the instructions, when I added PostgreSQL ANSI(x64), that is there and put the credentials of my database, the conecction was sucessfully but the excel continue to present the same message.

Anyway, I don´t know how to fix this problem yet.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What makes you say the connection is successful if you keep having the same message? Would you be able to confirm you do see the said driver in your Windows' ODBC data sources (64-bits)?

Comment: If you have created an ODBC datasource you can try using `Conexao.ConnectionString = "DSN=***;"`

Comment: Thanks. The problem is because my database is 64 bits and my excel was 32. I reinstalled the excel and it works!